# Bug on the active menu item in chrome and firefox - Wordpress/CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress website and I don't know how to fix this bug.
When I go back on the top of the page after have clicked on a menu button, that menu button keeps the color. It happens in Chrome and Firefox, Safari works fine.
I tried all the possible workaround :(

Can someone help me? [HERE](http://notifyme.org/homenew-rev-1/)

Thanks

Comment: You need to stye the :active and :focus pseudos for your nav buttons. If those states must be transparent then set them as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, there is background color & color set `:focus` selector. So when you click on the menu, it's in focus. Even if you scroll up, the focus remains there. And since you reached top, `Home` menu will get the class `active`. Therefore both links will show as active. Try adding this to prevent making the link active on focus,

`.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:not(.active) > a:focus {background-color:inherit !important;color: #4c3d3d !important;}`

Note: used `!important` since the other rules already have `!important`. Would recommend to not use `!important` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Its this css:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #c00000!important;
}
```

Remove that reference from the css, or override it.